# Can't select the last class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select the last child of these 3 classes which I've created. I presume this is a very simple fix.

I have created a snipped to show exactly where I am having trouble with.

```css
.homeimage     { width: 30%; position: relative; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; border: 1px solid blue; margin-right: 2%;}
.homeimage:last-class {  margin-right: 0; border: 1px soild yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 1</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->

<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 2</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->

<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 3</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->
```

Comment: There is no `last-class` pseudo-class in CSS. You should be looking at `last-child` or `last-of-type`.

Comment: What is not working?  I see a typo `soild` instead of `solid`,  maybe it just isn't applying the css because of the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that last-class doesn't exist.

I would recommend using either last-child to select the last element of a parent node.

Here is a modified version of your snippet using last-child.
Note that I had to create a wrapper div to trigger the last-child functionality.

```css
.homeimage     { width: 30%; position: relative; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; border: 1px solid blue; margin-right: 2%;}
.homeimage:last-child {  margin-right: 0; border: 1px solid yellow; }
```

```html
    <div>
    <div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
    &nbsp;
    <h4>Product 1</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- homeimage -->

    <div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
    &nbsp;
    <h4>Product 2</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- homeimage -->

    <div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
    &nbsp;
    <h4>Product 3</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- homeimage -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really can't think straight on Friday afternoons.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a workaround like this:

```css
.homeimage     { width: 30%; position: relative; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; border: 1px solid blue; margin-right: 2%;}
div.homeimage:last-of-type {  margin-right: 0; border: 1px solid yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 1</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->

<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 2</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->

<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 3</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->
<section>More content that does not mess up the :last-of-type selector</section>
```

Then make sure no other kind of div will be the last child. You can use other div-like tags like `<section>` or `<article>` as substitutes.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This Code nth-child

```css
.homeimage{ width: 30%; position: relative; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; border: 1px solid blue; margin-right: 2%;}
.homeimage:nth-child(3){  margin-right: 0; border: 1px solid yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 1</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->

<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 2</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->

<div class="homeimage">[image|2]<br />
&nbsp;
<h4>Product 3</h4>
</div>
<!-- homeimage -->
```